# Cant override variables - Adding Zurb-Foundation to Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, spree, zurb-foundation

I am trying to rewrite the frontend of our store with the help of the Zurb Foundation Framework, sadly, I run into quite some issues.

I included the *'zurb-foundation'* gem in my gemfile, and added following to the all.js and all.css in the assets/store directories

#### assets/stylesheets/store/all.css

```
*= require foundation
@import 'foundation';
```

#### assets/javascripts/store/all.js

```
//= require foundation
(document).foundation();
```

So far, I can use the classes as described in the zurb documentation - also, the different Items included in the Framework work well (Topbar, Orbit etc.)

Sadly I run into the issue, that I can't override the variables. 
I've created a file **'custom_variables.css.scss'** in the stylesheets/store directory to take care of those - But If i override them in there, it seems they dont take effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why this is not included in the Rails version. You can add the file that is automatically created by Compass called `_settings.scss`

You can download the file from github:

[Github file for settings.scss](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/templates/project/scss/_settings.scss)

and place it in your `app/assets/stylesheets`

then add the following line to your `foundation_and_overrides.scss` above `@import 'foundation';`

@import 'settings';

it should now look like this:

```
// Settings file to override Foundation variables

// You can find the variables for each component at the bottom of their
// doc page. We tried to name them to where they'd make sense just by reading them.
// Go to http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/ to find what you need.

@import 'settings'
@import 'foundation';
```

now you can just uncomment what you would like to change rather than trying to override the styles. This is how it works by default with Compass. I think the key is to change the sass variables before `@import 'foundation';` is called. Otherwise, you are just changing the variables after all of the css for foundation has been written out.

This has been working well for me using Foundation 4.0.8.

Comment: "you are just changing the variables after all of the css for foundation has been written out." -That was helpful

Comment: Looks like they might be addressing this in F4 Rails: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/1694

Comment: @JamesJamesJames in rails i can't able get the oundation_and_overrides.scss where should i get it because i create design with the help of compass

Comment: @VIVEkUI if you are using the latest zurb-foundation gem (v4.0.9), and installed with the latest rails generator per the f4 documentation, then there is a file in `app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss`. This is the equivalent of the sass/compass installed `sass/_settings.scss` file. If you are using rails, follow the f4 docs as it is important because it uses sprockets/assets for you automatically. If you are doing something outside of rails, look for a specific variant or use the compass version.

Comment: @JamesJamesJames yep got..:)